# Automate login details using vba referencing by name

Tags: vba, authentication, browser-automation

I have been attempting to automatically retrieve data from an intranet data site. The site is password protected. I have automated textbox entry before, however the **input** tags for username and password entry do **not** have an **id** property set which is causing me problems.

They do both have a **name** property set however I am unsure how to use this information to input the relevant username and password details.

The relevant source code from the login page:

```
<form method=POST action='../authentication.asp' name=frmLogin target='_parent'>
<table width='100%' height='100%'>
    <tr><td align=center valign=middle>
        <table class=dialogOuter>
            <tr class=dialogTitle><td>Logon</td></tr>
            <tr><td>
                <table class=dialogInner>
                    <tr>
                        <td width=100>User Name</td>
                        <td><input name=Username /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password</td>
                        <td><input type=password name=Password /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan=2 align=right>
                            <input class=Button type=submit value=Logon />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>            
            </td></tr>
        </table>
    </td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td align=center valign=bottom>Version: 4.4.1.8
  </td>
    </tr>
</table>            
<!-- Set the UserName input field to take focus, improved useability -->
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
document.frmLogin.Username.focus();
//-->
</script>
</form>
```

The website is being called within a class module using the variable **ie** to represent the internet explorer object. Normally when I input text in to a textbox I use code similar to `ie.document.getElementById("Username").innerText = Username` however this obviously refers to the object by the **id** property which is not set in this case. I have trawled through online guides and a lot of people seem to recommend code starting `ie.document.all("Username")` however I am unsure how to use this correctly and my intellisense doesn't seem to like the **all** command (as far as I can tell all relevant references are enabled).

All I require is for a string to be entered in to the Username and Password textboxes as I am comfortable with how to submit a form afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `getElementsByTagName("input")`. Because there could be more than one result ("...Element**s**..."), this will return an array, the first element being the username, the second the password.

**Usage:**

```
getElementsByTagName("input")(0) ' --> username
getElementsByTagName("input")(1) ' --> password
getElementsByTagName("input")(2) ' --> button
```

To read or write the content of the fields, use the `.Value` property.

**Explanation:**

`getElementsByTagName()` gets web page elements by their tag name (e.g. `<a>`, `<b>`, `<body>` etc.) as opposed to their ID like in your code snippet.

Comment: Thanks. In my **login** subroutine I changed the code to `ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")(0).value = Username` and this still brings up an automation error. There is no other code within this subroutine as the webpage is already open and stored in a global variable called **ie**.

Comment: Can you try: `.getAttribute("value")` instead of `.value`?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have tried it just to be 100% certain, but I still receive the same error. The issue is I am trying to set the text in the textboxes, my understanding of the `.getAttribute("value")` statement is that it is a read-only command?

Comment: Ok, one more :-).  Before setting the value with `.Value = ...` you need to set the focus to that field: `getElementsByTagName("input")(0).Focus`

Comment: I appreciate all your help with this, unfortunately the same error message is still being returned. I am still trying to read up on this and it has been mentioned that the fact it is an intranet page may be a problem, so I have even tried declaring the internet explorer browser using the line `Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium` instead of `Set ie = New InternetExplorer` (and the same with the variable declaration). This is becoming increasingly frustrating!

Comment: Is it possible you are not waiting for the website to be fully loaded (`Loop Until ie.readyState = 4` etc.)? Can you edit your VBA code into the question? Have you set your IE to be visible and what are you observing there?

Comment: Oh my god I am an amateur! Because I am coding this as a class module object I forgot to place that element of code in. It is not working yet, but the error code has changed to something I can deal with (one of the last 100+ attempts has to work lol). Thank you so much for your help, I am confident I can get this working now!